# Angular 5 interceptor ignores part of the code

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I have developed an angular 5 interceptor using this new HttpInterceptor module, and it works half way correctly. To elaborate more, my server side API provides a token refreshing service, so here is the desired process:
For each http request, the interceptor adds the bearer token to the request. If it fails with a 401 status, first the interceptor uses an internal service to refresh the bearer token, and then resends the original request with new access token and only if it fails then we will be redirected to the login page.

I have written the following code for my interceptor, and it works this much: It adds the bearer token to a request, if there is a 401, it uses the internal service to refresh the bearer token. But for some reason it does not resend the request with the newly refreshed token, basically that piece of the code just gets "ignored":

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("Interceptor engaged: " + this.auth.getAccessToken());

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getAccessToken()}`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log("first: ", event);
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 500) {
            console.log("attempting refresh.");
            return this.auth.refreshToken()
            .subscribe(
                d => 
                {
                    console.log("refresh success");
                    request = request.clone({
                        setHeaders: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getAccessToken()}`
                        }
                    });
                    return next.handle(request).do((event2: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                        console.log("***");
                        if (event2 instanceof HttpResponse){
                            console.log("second: ", event2)
                        }
                    }, (err2: any) => {
                        console.log("###");
                        if (err2 instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
                            console.log("Also where you redirect to login...");
                        }
                    });
                },
                d =>
                {
                    console.log("here is when you redirect...");
                    return Observable.throw(err);

                }
            )
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I can really use some help on why the second `return next.handle(request).do...` gets completely ignored. Thanks!

Comment: don't use subscribe (if you use subscribe, your're breaking the observable) If you want to make two calls, and the second depending of the first one or we need wait the response, use switchMap